# How to import AppDelegate in Cocoapod classes

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Can anyone suggest me a solution to import `AppDelegate` or any other custom classes in Cocoapod classes

Comment: why you do this? what problem to do this?

Comment: @vichevstefan i have added some libraries for animations using Cocoapod.Now i want to edit the pod classes depending for some classes.For that I want to import my classes there

Comment: You know that this is not right? If you will do another `pod install` you will have to modify files another time, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I had to import a `UIColor` category in my `cocoa pod` library, so what I did, I added it as an existing file in the library unchecking **Copy items if needed**. This will not create another copy of the file.

It is working well. May be you have to do the same.